# Creating new Tags

Tags: ruby, git, rugged

Just wondering if it is possible to create a new GIT tag using Rugged.  if so, an example would be greatly appreciated.

I'm basically just trying to create/move/delete tags on commit oids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see some examples in [`test/tag_test.rb`](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/blob/e96d26174b2bf763e9dd5dd2370e79f5e29077c9/test/tag_test.rb#L112-L115):

```
@repo = sandbox_init("testrepo.git")
@tag = @repo.tags.create('annotated_tag', "5b5b025afb0b4c913b4c338a42934a3863bf3644", {
  :message => "test tag message\n",
  :tagger => { :name => 'Scott', :email => 'schacon@gmail.com', :time => Time.now }
})
```

For deletion, see [`test/reference_test.rb`](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/blob/e96d26174b2bf763e9dd5dd2370e79f5e29077c9/test/reference_test.rb#L118-L122):

```
tag = @repo.tags["test"]

@repo.references.delete(tag)
refute @repo.references.exists?("refs/tags/test")
```

---

The [OP Chris Portman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3618141/chris-portman) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073625/creating-new-tags/25074172?noredirect=1#comment39061426_25074172) that:

> The create/delete methods are actually part of the [`TagCollection` class](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/blob/e96d26174b2bf763e9dd5dd2370e79f5e29077c9/ext/rugged/rugged_tag_collection.c).
>   Same with branches and the [`BranchCollection` class](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/blob/e96d26174b2bf763e9dd5dd2370e79f5e29077c9/ext/rugged/rugged_branch_collection.c).

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.  The create/delete methods are actually part of the TagCollection class.  Sane with branches and the BranchCollection class.

Comment: @ChrisPortman good point, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with links to those classes.